# How to assign value to cell depending on value from another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I want the value from column M to be set depending on the value from column L and comparing it to the value from column K. Any help would be great

I tried taking an Offset approach but nothing happens

```
If Intersect(Target, Columns("L")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each cl1 In Intersect(Target, Columns("L")) 


        If cl1 <= cl1.Offset(0, -1).Value Then

            cl1.Offset(0, 1).Value = cl1.Offset(0, -2).Value * cl1 * Sheet1.Range("M7").Value

        Else

            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Text"

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Is this code in a worksheet change event?

Comment: I think so. The value in M column is set when L column changes

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the actual `Sub` procedure definition, so we don't have to take guesses and make assumptions. See [mcve].

Comment: Have a read of this https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html and then post all your code please.

Comment: How can I set the target to L column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Column = 12 Then

    For Each cl1 In Intersect(Target, Columns("L"))


        If cl1.Value <= cl1.Offset(0, -1).Value Then

            cl1.Offset(0, 1).Value = cl1.Offset(0, -2).Value * cl1.Value * Range("M7").Value

        Else

            cl1.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Text"

        End If
    Next

End If


End Sub
```

Make sure your code Pasted in the Sheet you are working on.

---

[image: Like This]

Comment: Post your full code, if there are any changes I ll make them.

Comment: Yes `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` .. Under this ... But on the sheet you are working On

Comment: I do no see any changes on the M column

Comment: it's working on my System .. You sure you have Pasted the code in the Right Worksheet ?

Comment: See the Image @jvargas ... Like in the Image .

Comment: I have it like that. offset(0,-2) would be J column, right? maybe I am taking a bad approach

Comment: Yes, That's your J column. -1 would be `k` and -2 would be `J`

Comment: That's odd ... Try writing something in the Column L in a blank ROW...See if something happens.

Comment: Okay .. Then I am pretty confident that you have pasted your code on a wrong sheet. You have to paste the code on the sheet on which your Data is Present. Not in any Module or Thisworkbook or any other sheet. Share your workbook if you can, so that I can see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Check the question

Comment: On which sheet are you trying to change Values ?

Comment: On sheet1(TH-F46)

Comment: Okay .. So one check could be to remove any other code, other than in the answer and check only with answer. Also drop the `Sheet1.` in your if condition as you are on the same sheet. I have edited the answer ... Use this instead of your entire code as in the picture. If this works than you can check for error in the rest of your code.

Comment: Just Like I have pasted in My Screenshot .. Paste this code in your sheet, if it works then you can work further on your code.